# IntelliJ does not recognize SLF4J

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, graphhopper

I am trying to use Graph Hopper as a Maven dependency in IntelliJ.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphhopper/graphhopper-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphhopper</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphhopper-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but then, when i run the code, the console says:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I've seen some people having the same trouble as I, writing the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that IntelliJ is unable to recognize **slf4j-log4j12** dependency. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to recognize"? What exact error message or problematic behaviour do you get?

Comment: IntelliJ cannot find the slf4j-log4j12 artifact.

It literally says: Dependency org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12 not found.

Comment: Already solved it. Thanks. I've used instead the slf4j-nop dependency.